# Sort a 2D Array with primary key

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I'm trying to split each line of a text file and insert into an array list.

```
aa 04 cc ff gg rrr
aa 01 bb dd ee fff
aa 03 ff hh ee ttt
aa 05 dd ss ww ccc
```

1, How to store number as an integer and rest are strings in array list. (throwing Number Format Error with current code).

2, Is it possible to sort based on the integer while I am inserting to array with Java collections?

So far, I have,

```
List <Object> records = new ArrayList<Object>();
        bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFile()));
        String readLine;        

        while ((readLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                    List <Object> record = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    record.add(readLine.substring(flg_start, num_start).trim());
                    record.add(Integer.parseInt(readLine.substring(num_start-1, fld_start-1).trim())); // converting string to int and saving to record list, throwing Number Format Error.
```

let me rephrase my questions again,
How can I set record [1] as integer and rest as string?
What collection framework I can use to sort when I am adding into array?
I am expecting the end result in my array as a sorted list of around 1M records

```
aa 01 bb dd ee fff
aa 03 ff hh ee ttt
aa 04 cc ff gg rrr
aa 05 dd ss ww ccc
```

Comment: You've posted some requirements and some code but didn't tell us what the actual problem or question is.

Comment: I suspect an indexing problem. Try storing the substring results in separate variables and checking them (either by logging or with a debugger).

Comment: @tnw, I updated questions again below my code

Comment: Personally I cannot understand what is your question. My guess you need a map with Integer keys and String (or List<String>, I don't know) values. But I can't be sure as I can't understand the question. It whould help if you wrote the sample ouput you whish to have (as you've done with the sample input).

Comment: @ Yaroslav Rudykh, updated the expecting result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the data structure looks like you need `TreeMap` with `Integer` keys and `List` values. You should read the file and parse each line as @HaridwarJha described and for each line put new value with the parsed `Integer` key and `List` value formed of the parsed values.  With the `TreeMap` your data will be sorted by keys, i.e. by `Integer` values from you file.

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Object>>();
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
    List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] strArray=line.split(" ");
    row.add(strArray[0]);
    row.add(strArray[1]);
    row.add(strArray[2]);
    row.add(strArray[3]);
    row.add(strArray[4]);
    row.add(strArray[5]);
    map.put(new Integer(row.get(1)), row);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about Treemap to get auto sorting. For inserting into array, is it a good idea in performance wise?, since this file contains 1 million lines.

Comment: Or better I define Treemap with a class of variables?

Comment: TreeMap is rather efficiant structure: log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations. So I would try it first, test it and if there are performance issues I whould think about some other data structure. I'm not sure what you mean by "Treemap with a class of variables". And what do you mean by "any pseudo code with 2D TreeMap to get it sorted?". TreeMap is already sorted, you don't need to sort it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this and to access strArray you can use for loop or can be use regex[0...1] for parsing....
Here is simple one...try it
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List  records = new ArrayList();

```
    File file=new File("File Location");
    try {
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            String[] strArray=line.split(" ");
            records.add(new Integer(strArray[1]));
            records.add(new String(strArray[0]));
            records.add(new String(strArray[2]));
            records.add(new String(strArray[3]));
            records.add(new String(strArray[4]));
            records.add(new String(strArray[5]));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(Object tmp:records){
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
}
```